# Passing PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, post, events, dom-events

I have a PHP array:

```
foreach($xpath->query('//a') as $element) {
     $linklabel[] = $element->textContent;
     $link[] = $element->getAttribute("href");
     $i=$i+1;
}
```

I also have an HTML form:

```
<form name="keypad" id="form"  onSubmit="return pass(this)">
<input type="text" size="100%" length="25" value="" name="lcd">
<input type="button" value=" 1 " name="one" onClick="this.form.lcd.value+=this.value">
<input type="button" value=" 2 " name="two" onClick="this.form.lcd.value+=this.value">
<input type="button" value=" 0 " name="zero" onClick="this.form.lcd.value+=this.value">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Go" >
</form>
```

How can I write the onSubmit function `pass()` that takes the values from the keypad and sends the corresponding `$link[]` value to browse.php. For example, if `$link[20]='google.com';` , I want to pass `$link[20]` to browse.php if user enters `20` in the keypad and presses <kbd>Go</kbd>.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to output the PHP array in a way the Javascript can interpret, like as a Javascript array:

```
<?php
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
echo "var links = [";
foreach($links as $link)
    echo "'$link', ";
echo "];\n";
echo "</script>\n";
?>
```

You also need an element in the form the function can set:

```
<input type="hidden" name="url">
```

Then your Javascript function can index into the array and modify the form element:

```
function pass() {
    id = parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].lcd.value, 10);
    document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].url.value = links[id];
}
```

Your button values have spaces around them for some reason; they should just be the number, or `lcd.value` will end up with spaces throughout it. If you want the buttons to have padding use CSS.

Finally, you need to post the form if you're going to check `$_POST` on the other end, so change the tag to:

```
<form name="keypad" id="form" method="post" onSubmit="return pass()">
```

You can also just use `$_GET` on the target page

Comment: thanku you Michael.. let me try this...

Comment: error heppening when i tried to use the "for($links as $link) .... Is that because my coding problem, i am a beginner in php

Comment: can any body suggest a better idea. the **echo** idea is ruining my page with links

Comment: @Kiran My mistake, I wrote `for` instead of `foreach`. And you need to put the PHP part in script tags so the output is parsed as Javascript; I added one way to do it in my example

Comment: ok Michael, let this try this one....

Comment: !!! Its not working, probably because of error on my **<form>** code. The url is like this after i press the **Go** button **http://localhost/eye/browse.php?links_value=&lcd=+8+&Submit=Go**

Comment: My Browse.php is accepting variables as ** $url = $_POST['url'];
$var = fread_url($url);// function calling to get the page from curl ** I am new to php/javascript and i am forced to use it for a project.. Any help

Comment: @Kiran I changed some more things based on your comments

Comment: @Michael Mrozek . First of all, thx for ur support. But stills i am not able to pass it eventhough i am getting no errors. I like to show you my code. Do i make a new thread and post my entire code there. I am calling 'browse.php' from within 'browse.php' ... Is that the reason for error.....

Comment: I changed the method to **GET** now the url should be passed like this **http://localhost/eye/browse.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fisrc.ulster.ac.uk&submit=Submit** if everything is write for $link=http://isrc.ulster.ac.uk;.But it is now passing as **http://localhost/eye/browse.php?lcd=+1+&url=&Submit=Go** ...???what i need to do

Comment: The code worked after making a small change ** echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
echo "var links = [";
echo '"' . $link[0] . '"';
for($k=1;$k<$i;$k++){
 echo ',"' . $link[$k] . '"';
 }
echo "];\n";
echo "</script>\n";**

@ Michael Mrozek , thxxx